# how to Expand and collapse listview on click of button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have a listview in my fragment which occupies around 25% of my screen size. I also have a stripdown button. So, I want that when a strip down is clicked, that that time list view should expand and cover around 50% of the screen size and then again when i click stripUp it should return to it's former state. Can you please suggest some techniques through which i can achieve this.

My listview is like this: say i have 25 elements then initially only 10 of them are visible and to see others i will scroll down in Listview. After that when i click on stripDown button then number of visible items will increase to 15 and to see other elements i will scroll down.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use ExpandableListView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html how-to-use-expandablelistview http://androidword.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-use-expandablelistview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `ListView` section on the Api demo prior to honey comb. There are several examples that depict the usage of `ListView`s. It also includes an `ExpandableListView` and a regular `ListView` with an expandable effect.

You can find the demos from you Android SDK installation on your machine.

```
android-sdk/samples/android-x/ApiDemos
```